# Why do I have to create a concrete implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` in order to modify its members?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach, ienumerable

Why do I have to create a concrete implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` in order to modify its members in the `foreach` loop?

[This blog post (Exhibit 1)](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/02/linq-some-pitfalls-to-look-out-for/) explains the behavior, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

I've got a very simple code snippet here to reproduce the issue (C# 4.0 / .NET 4.0).

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //calling .ToList() on GetPeople() below will fix the issue
        var people = GetPeople();

        foreach (var item in people)
        {
            item.Age = DateTime.Now.Second;
        }

        foreach (var item in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Age is {0}", item.Age);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3)
        {
            i++;
            yield return new Person(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each time you iterate over `people`, it will execute the code in `GetPeople()` again - creating new instances of `Person`. The code in `GetPeople` does *not* run when you call `GetPeople()`; it only starts running when you call something:

```
var iterator = people.GetEnumerator();
iterator.MoveNext();
```

... which is what the `foreach` loop does.

If you call `ToList()`, that means you only execute the code in `GetPeople()` *once*, and store the references returned when iterating over the sequence. At that point, each time you iterator over the `List<Person>` you'll iterate over references to the same objects, so any modifications you make in one loop will be seen in another.

You may find it slightly easier to understand what's going on if you put logging (or a breakpoint) in `GetPeople()`. I have an [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) which goes into the implementation details, which *may* make things clearer too.

Comment: Jon, to tell you the truth, I was hoping you'd answer this one for me :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

GetPeople creates `People` on the fly. your first `foreach (var item in people)` creates `Peoples`, you set there ages, and after that, they are not stored anywhere.
Your second `foreach (var item in people)` creates a new set of `people`, they are new/different objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I wish I could accept both answers. +1